# Xamarin.iOS: How do I hide a UIView with subviews when clicked outside it without hiding it when clicked on the subviews?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I have a UIView, let's say MyView which contains a UILabel, UISegmentControl and a UIButton.

So

MyView.Hidden = false;

and

MyView.Tag = 1000;

to make sure it doesn't touch it.

now when I click outside that view I want it to hide, to that end I have some code which adds tap recognisers, ignores MyView (I hoped) and hides the view when you click outside. It removes the tab recognisers until MyView shows up again. It works, however when I click on the subviews of MyView (but NOT MyView itself) it calls ViewTap as well and thus disappears it as well. I cannot find why this happens...

```
class ViewTap : OutsideEditTap
        {
            public ViewTap(UIView MainView) {

                this.AddTarget(() => {

                    MyView.Hidden = true; 
                    RemoveTapGesture(this.View); 
                });
                CancelsTouchesInView = false;
            }
        }
        class OutsideEditTap : UITapGestureRecognizer
        {

        }


        public static void RemoveTapGesture(UIView view) {
            if (view.GestureRecognizers != null) for (int i = 0; i < view.GestureRecognizers.Length; i++) {

                    if (view.GestureRecognizers[i].IsSubClassOf(typeof(OutsideEditTap))) {
                        view.RemoveGestureRecognizer (view.GestureRecognizers [i]);
                    }

                }

            foreach (UIView subView in view.Subviews) {
                RemoveTapGesture (subView);
            }

        }

        public static  void AddTapGesture(UIView view,  UIView MainView) {

                OutsideEditTap tap = null;

                if (view.Tag != 1000) { // skip MyView 
                    tap = new ViewTap (MainView);
                    view.AddGestureRecognizer (tap);
                    foreach (UIView subView in view.Subviews) {
                        AddTapGesture (subView, MainView);
                    }
                } 


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sure this is probably not the best method (I don't think the whole idea was not the best implementation to begin with, but no-one provided any alternatives unfortunately); the solution I used to solve this was to add to the AddTarget Action:

```
var p = this.LocationOfTouch(0, this.View); 
if (MyView.Frame.Contains(p)) { return; }
```

which works well. I would still like to hear a better way of doing this.